# Trying to write hostname to a file every time the loop finds a new machine in the network

Tags: python, networking

I am trying to look for all the Windows computers on a network. Every time the program finds a computer in the network that is up and running, it will open a new file for that computer. In the file, I want to see the name of the machine, and its IP address.

Once I'm done with that, I would like to log the installed apps on a particular computer onto that machine's file, which is why I have a new file for every computer that the program finds.

However, when I run it, the machine has the same name every time. I have tried using import socket, but whenever I use any method that comes with it, I get an error saying that the socket has no attribute. I need from socket import * for my is_up method to work.

Here is my code:

```
from socket import *

ipa = '192.168.1.'

def is_up(adr):
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(0.01)
    if not s.connect_ex((adr, 135)):
        s.close()
        return 1
    else:
        s.close()

def main():
    for i in range(1, 256):
        adr = ipa + str(i)
        if is_up(adr):
            f = open("Machine " + str(i) + ".txt", "w+")
            f.write('%s \t- %s \n' % ("Name: " + gethostname(), adr))

        if is_up(adr):
            print(gethostbyaddr(adr))

main()
```

**Edit**: I have put the new code here to reflect the use of `gethostbyaddr(adr)`. I am still getting the following error:

> [Errno 11004] host not found

```
def main():
    for i in range(1, 256):
        adr = ipa + str(i)
        if is_up(adr):
            print(gethostbyaddr(adr))
```

**Traceback** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/eread/PycharmProjects/SoftwareScanner/SoftwareScanner", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/eread/PycharmProjects/SoftwareScanner/SoftwareScanner", line 20, in main
    print(gethostbyaddr(adr))
socket.herror: [Errno 11004] host not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the function used to get the hostname, [`gethostname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname) returns the name of the machine where you're executing the script.

If you want the name of the distant machine you're inspecting, you need another function like [`gethostbyaddr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr), which returns a tuple of 3 members : name, list of aliases and list of IPs

```
if is_up(adr):
    print(gethostbyaddr(adr))

#>>> ('machine_name', [], ['192.168.1.14'])
```

The other advantage of using such a function, as you get all details in one object, i think you have no need to use a file to store those, at least before using them in the second part of your script.

You can unpack the values returned by `gethostbyaddr` to declare the variables you need in the next part :

```
host_name, _, adresses = gethostbyaddr(adr)
print(host_name)
print(adresses[0]) #this member is a list, use index to access the first

#>>> result :
#machine_name
#192.168.1.14
```

Comment: I tried using gethostbyaddr(adr), but I get an error that says: socket.herror: [Errno 11004] host not found

Comment: it's weird that the function `is_up` could return 1 if the host is not found, where did you add `gethostbyaddr(adr)` in your code ?

Comment: I used it to replace gethostname().

Comment: Oh, I just realized you put gethostbyaddr(adr) in the main function, and printed it. My bad. I am trying that right now.

Comment: i cant understand why... could you edit your question to add the new code, and the traceback of error ?

Comment: I just did it. The code now shows what I currently have.